# How can I use a specific wordpress page template if certain words are used in page title

Tags: wp-query, pages, page-template, wp-title

I'm creating a wordpress theme for a client to use in his existent wordpress site. Anyways, I've completed the theme except one specific thing. I see that he has lots of pages with the keyword Module in the title. Example of the title would be "How to create this product: Module 1." In his previous theme, they had a wordpress page template - page-module.php use specifically for these pages. However, I created a wp page template in my theme with the same name but when I go to any of these pages, it is displaying the default page.php template instead of the page-module.php template. When I switch back to his theme, it work fine with his page-module.php template but when I switch by to my theme, it doesn't work. Can someone please help me understand why it's not working with my theme?

Comment: Are you asking how selectable page templates work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the template to use in the fly based on the type of page you're viewing. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'portfolio' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'portfolio-page-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

You could use that in conjunction with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object to check out information about the page requested, like the title.

This assumes you didn't just set your page template on the page itself.

[image: setting Page Template]

Comment: Hi @jgraup, thanks for the reply. All the page templates are set to default. I added the code you give me to the function file of my theme but it is still not working. I don't know why.

Comment: The code is an example, which checks for a specific page, you'd need to supply your own custom condition . At the very least just remove everything except for your custom template path to make sure that works. Then come up with a way to only function on the required pages.

Comment: My page template is page-module.php, so this is how I did it. 
`code`
add_filter( 'template_include', 'module_page_template', 99 );

    function module_page_template ( $template ) {

 if ( is_page( 'module' )  ) {
  $new_template = locate_template( array( 'page-module.php'          ) );
  if ( '' != $new_template ) {
   return $new_template ;
  }
 }

 return $template;
    }

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they were using custom page templates. You'll want to read about [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) on the codex.